# Why does Length() not show up in the Get-Member of an array?

Tags: powershell

When I pipe an array into `Get-Member`, the Length() method doesn't show up, even though it exists.

Why is that, and what do I need to do to display all of the members?

```
> $a = @(0,1)
> $a.Length
2
> $a | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Int32

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
CompareTo   Method     int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(int value), int IComparable.CompareT... Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(int obj), bool IEquatable[int].Equals(int ... GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
GetTypeCode Method     System.TypeCode GetTypeCode(), System.TypeCode IConvertible.GetTypeCode()
ToBoolean   Method     bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToByte      Method     byte IConvertible.ToByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToChar      Method     char IConvertible.ToChar(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToDateTime  Method     datetime IConvertible.ToDateTime(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToDecimal   Method     decimal IConvertible.ToDecimal(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToDouble    Method     double IConvertible.ToDouble(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToInt16     Method     int16 IConvertible.ToInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToInt32     Method     int IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToInt64     Method     long IConvertible.ToInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToSByte     Method     sbyte IConvertible.ToSByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToSingle    Method     float IConvertible.ToSingle(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToString    Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string format), string ToString(System.IFormatProvi... ToType      Method     System.Object IConvertible.ToType(type conversionType, System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUInt16    Method     uint16 IConvertible.ToUInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUInt32    Method     uint32 IConvertible.ToUInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUInt64    Method     uint64 IConvertible.ToUInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `.Length` property is of an array object as a whole.

Per this article from MS [About Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6)

> ...PowerShell sends the items one at a time and Get-Member returns the
>   type of each item in the array, ignoring duplicates...

The article also states to use `Get-Member -InputObject $a` to see the methods, properties, etc. of the array object.

Comment: You can also use `,@(1,2) | get-member`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of piping, if you use get-member directly:

```
Get-Member -InputObject $a
```

One thing I notice is that if you enter `$a.GetType()`, you'll appropriately see that you have a System.Array object.  However when you enter `$a | gm` it's showing System.Int32 as if Powershell was enumerating the array after the pipe.